# How to implement interface in derived class or through partial classes?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have a partial class being generated by a tool.

**Foo.cs**

```
public partial class Foo {
    [SomeAttribute()]
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

I need to implement the following interface for `Foo` without touching Foo.cs:

**IFoo.cs**

```
public interface IFoo {
    string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

Extending `Foo` is also an option, but re-implementing the `Bar` property isn't.

**Can this be done?**

Comment: why you can not extend Foo:IFoo, if this what you're asking for?

Comment: @Tigran: I cannot touch the Foo.cs file

Comment: @DBM: As stated elswhere.. `Bar` should be public

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What prevents you from doing this again in another file?

```
public partial class Foo : IFoo
{
}
```

Since `Bar` property already exists, it wont be needed to reimplement it.

Or in a new class

```
public class FooExtended : Foo, IFoo
{
}
```

Again, you won't need to implement `Bar` since Foo implements it already.

Comment: The option with partial class has limitation. You need to put the file in the same assembly. The option with extended class should work universally. What is the compile error?

Comment: You can't re-implement Bar anyway, unless it's virtual, so this is the right way to do it.

Comment: what was the error? It should work I've done this before. note that the other partial class file needs to be in the same namespace.

Comment: 'FooExtended' does not implement interface member 'IFoo.Bar'

Comment: @DBM: My bad, `Bar` is public!

Comment: It does work. The generated file contained more classes. I was 'partialing' the wrong class!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a partial class for Foo that implements IFoo but with the Bar property not being public it won't work.

If Bar property was public:

```
partial class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

interface IFoo
{
    string Bar { get; set; }
}

partial class Foo : IFoo
{

}
```

Comment: Please see my @Tomislav Markovski, `Bar` should be public

Answer (score 1):

As `Bar` is private, here's what you're looking for:

```
public partial class Foo : IFoo
{
    string IFoo.Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Bar;  // Returns the private value of your existing Bar private field
        }
        set
        {
            this.Bar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, this is confusing and should be avoided if possible.

*EDIT*: Okay, you've changed your question, so as `Bar` is now public, there is no more problem as `Bar` is always implemented in `Foo`.